# updateCollapse() can't switch style with mycustomstyle in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinybs

I can change the panel style in ("success", "info", "danger" ...) randomly, but once I change it to my customized style, I can't change it anymore

if `updateCollapse()` can't work, I'm also looking for other solutions, I've tried using `shinyjs::addClass()`, but it seems that the panel in bsCollapse does not have an id

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
    ui <- fluidPage(
        tags$head(tags$style(
            "
            .panel-custom {
            border-color: #d6e9c6;
            }
            .panel-custom .panel-heading {
            color: #3c763d;
            background-color: yellow;
            border-color: #d6e9c6;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            }
            .panel-custom .panel-heading::after {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #ff0000;
            }
            "
        )),
        bsCollapse(id = "bs", open = "panel1",
            bsCollapsePanel("panel1",
                actionButton("success", "success"),
                actionButton("info", "info"),
                actionButton("warning", "warning"),
                actionButton("danger", "danger"),
                br(),
                actionButton("custom", "custom")
            )
        )
    ),
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        observeEvent(input$success, {
            updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "success"))
        })
        observeEvent(input$info, {
            updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "info"))
        })
        observeEvent(input$warning, {
            updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "warning"))
        })
        observeEvent(input$danger, {
            updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "danger"))
        })
        observeEvent(input$custom, {
            updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "custom"))
        })
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen that `panel-custom` class was not removed when you click on yours non custom buttons.

So I've removed this class on all non custom buttons.

So you have to add to your code:

- at the beginning of ui side : `shinyjs::useShinyjs()`

  - > This function must be called from a Shiny app's UI in order for all other shinyjs functions to work.
- In the declaration of css : `tags$style(type = "text/css",HTML(`. Note mostly `HTML()` (for example css `>` become `&gt;` without `HTML()`)
- inside every non custom buttons (server side) `shinyjs::removeClass(id=NULL, selector = "#bs .panel", class = "panel-custom")`. Note `id=NULL` is mandatory if you want css `selector` works.
- the panel has no id but if you have more than one you should use CSS :nth-child() Selector

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css",HTML(
      "
            .panel-custom {
              border-color: #d6e9c6;
            }
            .panel-custom .panel-heading {
              color: #3c763d;
              background-color: yellow;
              border-color: #d6e9c6;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: space-between;
              align-items: center;
            }
            .panel-custom .panel-heading::after {
              content: '';
              display: inline-block;
              width: 16px;
              height: 16px;
              border-radius: 50%;
             background-color: #ff0000;
            }
            ")
    )),
    
    
    bsCollapse(id = "bs", open = "panel1",
               bsCollapsePanel("panel1",
                               actionButton("success", "success"),
                               actionButton("info", "info"),
                               actionButton("warning", "warning"),
                               actionButton("danger", "danger"),
                               br(),
                               actionButton("custom", "custom")
               )
    )
    
  ),
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$success, { 
      
      shinyjs::removeClass(id=NULL,selector = "#bs .panel", class = "panel-custom")
      updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "success"))
    })
    observeEvent(input$info, {
      shinyjs::removeClass(id=NULL,selector = "#bs .panel", class = "panel-custom")
      updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "info"))
    })
    observeEvent(input$warning, {
      shinyjs::removeClass(id=NULL,selector = "#bs .panel", class = "panel-custom")
      updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "warning"))
    })
    observeEvent(input$danger, {
      shinyjs::removeClass(id=NULL,selector = "#bs .panel", class = "panel-custom")
      updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "danger"))
    })
    observeEvent(input$custom, {
      updateCollapse(session, "bs", style = list("panel1" = "custom"))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: When the answer is working and has answered your question you can accept it by clicking the `v` below the vote :)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I'm still confused as to why that didn't work for me.

Comment: Look at with F12 (debug mode in browsers). And watch for HTML update after each click: with these observations I have seen for example that class `panel-custom` didn't disappeared, so the `removeClass`, that `removeClass` didn't work, so `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` and `HTML()` etc....  Also to have `selector = "#bs .panel"` These observations explained to me why it didn't work, try and observe the HTML by F12/Inspector in your browser for your real application :)

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I mean I'm always trying to figure out why my original code doesn't work, why my custom classes are any different from those, and why they can be switched freely but the custom classes can't.

Comment: OK, I check the `js` of shinyBS, yes, you are always right, Thank you again, I found shinyBS also use `removeClass` and `addClass` to achieve style change, just look like switch https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/blob/c329f8ce43e44579cafbb16fc3109fb69d403e57/inst/www/shinyBS.js#L79